# Include external po file for 3th party plugin to theme

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, translation

I used 3th party plugin in my theme but some of them don't have my target language support.I want to add new language support to these plugins from my theme plugin.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If discussed plugin already uses [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/load_plugin_textdomain) function to load its translations, usually it is enough to place `<plugin_name>-<locale_code>.mo` file to the `wp-content/languages/plugins` directory. If it doesn't (or you can't do it for some reason), you can use `init` hook to load its translation via your `functions.php`. Here is an example from one of my child themes:

```php
function load_plugin_translations() {
    if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce-payment-status/woocommerce-payment-status.php' ) ) {
        load_textdomain( 'woocommerce_payment_status', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/woocommerce_payment_status-' . get_user_locale() . '.mo' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'load_plugin_translations' );
```

Here I use `woocommerce_payment_status-<locale>.mo` translation file from the `languages` folder under my child theme. Replace `woocommerce-payment-status/woocommerce-payment-status.php` plugin ID and `woocommerce_payment_status` textdomain ID according to your plugin.